# What would happen if the Vanishing Cabinet in the Hogwarts Room of Requirement was used by two people at once?

Tags: harry-potter

If the Vanishing Cabinet in Hogwart’s Room of Requirement was being used by someone else, and therefore in a different configuration, what would happen to a person going from  Borgin and Burkes Vanishing Cabinet to Hogwart’s Vanishing Cabinet at the same time the current user of  Hogwart’s Room of Requirement is using it for personal reasons?

Comment: What makes you believe that the RoR Vanishing Cabinet can just be up and reconfigured?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're confusing the Vanishing Cabinet's functionality with the Room of Requirement's functionality here, but it sounds like you are. The Vanishing Cabinet is essentially just a means of magical transportation between two linked cabinets. The Room of Requirement is what can be reconfigured to meet the occupant's needs.

Comment: So, to clarify, are you asking what would happen if you tried to travel from Borgin and Burkes to Hogwarts when the Room of Requirement is being used for something other than the "hide broken things" room?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yes.

Answer (score 4):

All mentions in the books for "Vanishing Cabinets" talk about them as "pairs". They do not seem to resemble "Phone booths" where you can simply "call" any other phone booth but they are linked to each other directly. So: Using another "path" from a third cabinet seams not to be feasible within the Potter universe.

> Then, as though he could not help himself, he said, “I had to mend that broken **Vanishing Cabinet** that no one’s used for years. The one Montague got lost in last year.”
>   “Aaaah.” Dumbledore’s sigh was half a groan. He closed his eyes for a moment. “That was clever…**there is a pair, I take it**?”
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince
>
>   Chapter 27 - THE LIGHTNING-STRUCK TOWER</sub>

and

> “I do,” said Harry, and he explained, briefly, about **the pair of Vanishing Cabinets** and the magical pathway they formed. “So they got in through the Room of Requirement.”
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince
>
>   Chapter 29 - THE PHOENIX LAMENT</sub>